# Suppress Code Analysis For a Single JS File

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

My project has a vendor.js file that is showing warnings (TS7027 unreachable code detected).

I don't want to fix those warnings since it's vendors code. But I don't want to see those warnings either.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio (2017) to suppress all messages for this file (e.g. with the CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage attribute)?

I am not using resharper, just the built-in code analysis tool.